# Confusion between informant, informer, and someone who simply gives some information

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Confusion:

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/informant?q=informant):

> informant (synonym informer): *a person who gives secret information about somebody/something **to the police** or a newspaper*

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/informant):

> informant: *someone who gives information to another person or organization* BUT the example is: *a **police/secret** informant*

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/informant):

> informant: *a person who gives information to the police about **secret or criminal activities***

So, as I read, *informant/informer* deals with information passed on to some authorities secretly.

**The Question**

I am **not talking** of someone who is giving me information secretly or with any bad intention. S/he is just a source of information. S/he is *not paid* or kept on a **job** to pass on the information.

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who **gave me information** about someone/thing **but**...

> S/he's not paid 
>  S/he's not kept for that job exclusively 
>  S/he's does not give me information regularly 
>  S/he's not a professional in passing the information. 
>  S/he doesn't report to anyone.

Comment: An informant certainly doesn't have to be a police informant. There are informants in linguistics.

Comment: I think you already have the best word: *source*. You don't seem to want *tale-teller* or *rumor spreader*, I think. I wouldn't use *informer* myself, but *informant* is probably not off limits.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm skeptical using 'source' because asking-'**What** is your source' seems okay, but '**Who** is your source'!!!

Comment: @MaulikV You can try searching for the string "source tipped me off".

Comment: @MaulikV "Who is your source?" is perfectly reasonable, especially in the context of journalism.

Answer (score 1):

As previously told and verified on OxfDE:

"a person from whom a linguist or anthropologist obtains information about language, dialect or culture."

I think "source" is tailored on what you're saying. J

Answer (score -1):

IMO, tittle-tattler is a word that fits in your search. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/tittle-tattler) says:

> Tittle-tattler: n. One who circulates idle gossip; a trifling tattler.

However, I could not find this word in any other dictionaries. But, tattler word is given [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tattler?s=t).

[Tittle-tattle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tittle-tattle) is a synonym for gossips.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with 'gossip'. It's genuine information! Say, your colleague Kate told you that Tina (another colleague) is suffering from typhoid and is hospitalized. Now, Kate is neither an *informer/informant* **nor** title-tattle!